# Modify a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am a new programmer currently working on a project. I was wondering how to manipulate every element in a data frame in R. I want to multiply all of the numbers in a particular column in my data frame by -1, how would I do this?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

In `R`, these operations are vectorized.  So, simply multiply by that number and assign it to the particular column. (Here, "col1" is the name of the column and 'df1' is the data.frame object name)

```
df1[, "col1"] <- df1[, "col1"] * -1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 6:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're dealing with dataframes in `R`, it would be a good idea to learn `dplyr` package and the related functions. A `dplyr` solution would be :

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- mutate(df1, col1 = -1 * col1)
```